# Can't find information on Suntour XOR 100 fork

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

This [Rockrider 540 MTB description](https://www.decathlon.in/p/8359147_rockrider-540-mountain-terrain-bike.html#/237-413-m) says it has a Suntour XOR 100 fork. I am not able to find it on the Suntour website.

Anyone knows what does XOR stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"XOR" stands for nothing, it's a typo in "XCR". [Here's a review](https://www.choosemybicycle.com/en/woc/expert-reviews/btwin-rockrider-540-2017-review) of this bike where you can read the model clearly on photos and the [XCR aggregate page on Suntour's website](http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/home/components/fork/?Model=%22XCR%22).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the decathlon.in page is for the retail outlet.

There is a separate [Rockrider 540](https://www.btwin.com/en/mountain-bikes/sport-mountain-bikes/20068-275-rockrider-540-mountain-bike-red.html) page on the BTwin site that says the bike has Suntour *XCR* 100mm travel forks.

I assume there is an error on the Decathlon page.